# Read and display data from file on an app screen using jetpack compose

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am using jetpack compose and kotlin in android studio to build an app.
This app would be able to display certain songs like title and author. I came up with the idea of using a JSON file to write all my data so the app could read the data and display it on the "Musics Screen" of the app.
This is what my project looks like :

[image: Project tree]

To achieve this goal I made some tests.
First, by using `applicationContext.assets.open("musics.json")` in the MainActivity file:

```kotlin
data class MyData(
    val title: String,
    val author: String,
)

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    // Routing object
    // lateinit var navController: NavHostController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
          
                //navController = rememberNavController()

                val jsonString = applicationContext.assets
                    .open("musics.json")
                    .bufferedReader()
                    .use { it.readText() }

            val dataArray = JSONArray(jsonString)
            val dataList = mutableListOf<MyData>()

            for (i in 0 until dataArray.length()) {
                val item = dataArray.getJSONObject(i)
                val title = item.getString("title")
                val author = item.getString("author")
                dataList.add(MyData(title, author))
            }

            LazyColumn {
                items(dataList.size) {
                    Row {
                            Text(dataList[it].title)
                            Text(dataList[it].author)
                        }
                }
            }

            // entry point of my navigation graph
            // SetupNavGraph(navController = navController)


        }
    }
}
```

That method worked really well but I wanted to display the datas on the MusicsScreen.
And unfortunately, the applicationContext object that I used earlier is only available in the MainActivity class. So I had to use other methods.

I tried the File.io library in the MusicsScreen file but it didn't work properly and resulted in an error.
Does anyone have an idea how to make this work?

PS : I'm a beginner in mobile development and I don't know the JetPack Compose framework well so if you think I should deepen some point in my learning, don't hesitate to let me know.

Comment: `val jsonString = applicationContext.assets` can you change that to: `val jsonString = assets` ?

Comment: I think the subject of your post should be: `How to read a file from assets?` And on the firsty line of your post you should tell that you put a file in assets.

Comment: I can use the keyword assets but it allow me to use assets.open( ) only in the MainActivity so it does not solve my problem. Furethermore I could place my json anywhere, it does not matter for me if it placed in assets or not.

Comment: I just need an efficient way to read and display datas on one of my applicaion screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay let me share a good way to read and display data from a file hope it helps you , check the below code

First make `MusicUtils` file and paste the below code there

```
fun getJsonDataFromAsset(
    context: Context,
    fileName: String
): String? {
    val jsonString: String
    try {
        jsonString = context.assets.open(fileName).bufferedReader().use {
            it.readText()
        }
    } catch (exp: IOException) {
        exp.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }

    return jsonString
}

fun musicList(context: Context): MutableList<MyData> {
    val jsonFileString = getJsonDataFromAsset(context = context, "musics.json")
    val type = object : TypeToken<List<MyData>>() {}.type
    return Gson().fromJson(jsonFileString, type)
}

data class MyData(
    val title: String,
    val author: String,
)
```

Now the `musicList` function contains the list of musics data , call this function where ever you want. Hope this will work

Comment: I still have to give a context argument in this code. First I don't really understand what are exactly those context objects. Then, which context argument should I pass if I call your musiclist function from the MusicsScreen file ?

Comment: Ok! I finally got it! I can use ```context = LocalContext.current``` in other files like MusicsScreen. Thank you, your code seems to work. But I still can't understand what context objects stand for.